# Reindex Magento Error On MAMP ( Mac os x )

Tags: reindex

I am new to magento and i have just installed Magento locally on my mac.
When i login into the Magento admin panel i get this error :

"One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running."

After a bit of research i found that i need to run the following command from the root directory of my Magento installation.

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

However i keep getting this message after running the command "Magento supports PHP 5.6, 7.0.2, and 7.0.6 or later. Please read http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v1.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html%   "

My PHP version is 7.0.8 so i'm not sure why i am getting this error.

Thanks !

Comment: Try to run > php -v in your CLI and check version. It might be different from web one.

Comment: Yep , you're right it shows PHP 5.5.27. How do i change it to the one MAMP uses?

Comment: I am using https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew to update php version.

Comment: Ugh, I had a hell of a time configuring Magento 2 dev site on MAMP Pro. I used AMPPS lamp stack and had better luck, although it ran awfully slow.

Comment: i managed to change the php version but now i am getting this :
  
zsh: permission denied: bin/magento

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it with setting the right version of PHP and then "chmod u+x bin/magento" and then bin/magento indexer:reindex